# Javascript: On Deletion Behavior

Tags: javascript, overriding

I am reading an [interesting article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#theory) on understanding delete in JS.

I understand that properties created via *variable declaration* **cannot** be deleted, or more precisely, has the `DontDelete` attribute, while properties created via *property assignment* **can** be deleted.

But I'm confused with how property overloading works with this idea:

```
> var GLOBAL_OBJECT = this;
undefined

> var declared = "I cannot be deleted";
undefined

> delete declared;
false

> assigned = "I can be deleted";
'I can be deleted'

> delete assigned;
true

> // Now, I will override `declared` ...

> declared = "I am overrided - now deletable?";
'I am overrided - now deletable?'

> declared;
'I am overrided - now deletable?'

> delete declared;
false
```

This seems to me is that property attributes are **predetermined** when properties are created within the Variable Object. So, when you attempt to override a property, you can expect that it will be overridden but that the property attributes will not.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

What you call "override" a property is actually a regular assignment. You simply change the value of the variable. All the attributes of the variable remain the same, including the DontDelete you mentioned.

In the case of the `assigned` variable in your example, the variable was defined implicitly, not declared with the `var` keyword and that is what makes it able to be deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of the overloading principle in other OO languages (i.e. method overloading, operator overloading) where the latest declarations will either stack or replace their existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the article too hastily.

Here is a quote from the article that addresses this topic,

> Note that it is during property creation that attributes are determined (i.e. none are set). Later assignments don't modify attributes of existing property. It's important to understand this distinction.